# request options is missing in angular 6

Tags: upgrade, angular6

I have upgraded angular 4 to 6 and I used `RequestOptions` to send data with http delete request like this

```
return this.http.delete(Config.apiUrl, new RequestOptions({
  headers: this.heders,
  body: data
})).map(res=>res.json());
```

now after upgraded I cant find  `RequestOptions`

import process in angular 4

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

import process in angular 6

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpClient.prototype.delete()](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete) is overloaded.

The easiest way is to pass a plain object:

```
return this.http.delete(Config.apiUrl, {
  headers: this.heders,//misspelt
  body: data
}).map(res=>res.json());
```

Additionally, if you wanted more control over the request, you could construct an [HttpRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) and pass it to [HttpClient.prototype.request().](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request)

Comment: thanks man it's working but I had to defined the interface like 

export interface RequestOptions {
  headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | Array<string> };
  body?: any;
}

to assign the body